# Why my web won't show the right font when I use local Dojo CSS?

Tags: html, css, dojo

I am quite newbie in HTML design, and having trouble of understanding why my web design won't display the correct font. If I use this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

The font shown right. But if I use my local copy of Dojo 1.6.1, by using this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dojo161/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dojo161/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dojo161/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

it won't display the same font for html body. 
What did I do wrong?

Thanks,
PS : I already inspect using Google Chrome webkit, the resources (*.css) were accessible

Comment: Can you inspect in chrome and find out what rule(s) are missing (at least when it comes to fonts)?

Comment: What happens if you  change the DSN version from 1.5 to 1.6 as well?

Comment: @Smamatti : sorry, my mistake. the sytle.css is not missing. I'll edit my question

Comment: @missingno : I think you're right, I check the firebug console, and it display error in dojo.js (what can I do if the dojo.js is error anyway?). Here it's : SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
(function(){var _1=null;if((_1||(typeo...setTimeout(dojo._loadInit,100);}})();

Comment: @missingno : Ok, downloading 1.5.1 I hope it solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @missingno. It's okay now with the 1.5.1. If you want, you can move your comment to answer section, so that I can accept it as the answer. Anyway, there is stll the error about missing ) in parentetical, but now it's in bootsrap.js. After I did a little code reading, it's because my sql query is not right. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.5 has different definitions in the `claro.css` than 1.6.1.

```
.claro {
    font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; // <-- !!!
    font-size: .688em;
    color: #131313;
}

.claro .dijitCalendarDateTemplate {
    font-family: Arial;
    // ...
}

/* h1 to h6, p, ol, ul etc. diffes in for example:
    - font-size
    - font-weight
    - line-height
*/
```

Comment: These styles are part of Claro's document.css, which was imported by claro.css (and thus flattened into it in builds) in 1.5.  However, this was kind of a mistake, since it includes base styles that could conflict with a site's existing base styles.  Thus, that import was taken out in 1.6, but the resource still exists.  If you still want these styles in 1.6, load dijit/themes/claro/document.css in addition to claro.css.

Comment: Thanks @KenFranqueiro for the  tips!. Currently I stick to 1.5. But your tip making me easier to migrate to 1.6